# Undefined is not valid JSON

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting the error above on this VERY simple React component, but to me everything seems to be ok, so i don´t get why i´m getting the error. Im usign next.js 13.3.0.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse
> ()

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  handleClick: () => void;
  name: string;
}

const Button = ({ handleClick, name }: Props) => {
  console.log(`${name} renderizado`);
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{name}</button>;
};

export default function Home() {
  const [countOne, setCountOne] = useState(0);
  const [countTwo, setCountTwo] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        handleClick={() => setCountOne((prev) => prev + 1)}
        name="button1"
      />
      <Button
        handleClick={() => setCountTwo((prev) => prev + 1)}
        name="button2"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

**stack trace**
[image]

Comment: It seems unlikely this is where the error actually is coming from given there are no `JSON.parse` calls in this file. Possibly a framework type error -- could you post the full stack trace? Does it happen when the component mounts or on some other user action?

Comment: It happens when the component mounts, and there are no components other than the ones created in a new next project,  and i am only working on the Home component.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function Home(){}
```

exporting a client component like the above is a bug I think after next.js 13.2. change it to

```
const Home=()=>{}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't give specific solution but props interface can do this:

```
interface Props {
  handleClick: () => void;
  name: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```